# SSRS Combining values within columns from multiple rows when grouped

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, reporting-services

I feel like this should be relatively easy to do in a SSRS report. Using VS 2010. I have a table that comes in from a basic sql query. Just dropping the columns into the a table in visual studio. I want to group the table by company first, which I do via the row group properties. I have a table that looks like this.

```
 Company     Contact     ContactSub    SubCert    Year

  Bank3       Joey        Steven.B      A         2010
  Bank2       Dave        James         A         2010
  Bank2       Dave        Steve         B         2010
  Bank2       Dave        Mark          B         2010
  Bank2       Dave        James         A         2011
  Bank2       Dave        Steve         A         2011
  Bank2       Dave        Mark          B         2011
  Bank2       Dave        James         A         2012
  Bank2       Dave        Steve         A         2012
  Bank2       Dave        Mark          A         2012
```

I now want to combine the Contact Subs and their subcert joined into one row. BUT only using the most recent year. Because some ContactSub may have had their SubCert upgraded to an A from a B.

```
 Company       Contact            ContactSub            SubCert     Year

  Bank3         Joey             Steven.B               A           2010
  Bank2         Dave             James,Steve,Mark       A,A,A       2012
```

I added an additional gorup by property, the "Year" column to the row and used this formula for the ContactSub and SubCert columns in the table:

```
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!Company.Value,Fields!Company.Value,Fields!SubCert.Value,"DataSet Name"),",")
```

But this returned me:

```
 Company     Contact     ContactSub                 SubCert     Year

  Bank3       Joey        Steven.B                   A          2010
  Bank2       Dave        James,Steve,Mark,James     A,B,B,A,   2012
                          Steve,Mark,James, Steve    A,B,A,A,
                          Mark                       A
```

How could I clarify my formula to make it say for only the newest year instead of using the values for all years?

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With your data:

[image]

And a table grouped on `Company`:

[image]

I use the following expressions:

**ContactSub**

```
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!Company.Value & Max(Fields!Year.Value)
    , Fields!Company.Value & Fields!Year.Value
    , Fields!ContactSub.Value
    , "DataSet1"), ",")
```

**SubCert**

```
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!Company.Value & Max(Fields!Year.Value)
    , Fields!Company.Value & Fields!Year.Value
    , Fields!SubCert.Value
    , "DataSet1"), ",")
```

You can see I'm using `Max(Fields!Year.Value)` as well as `Fields!Company.Value` to only match on the highest year in the `LookupSet` expression.

This gives the required results:

[image]

Comment: Hmm... I seem to still be getting the same exact thing returned. Everything I've read validates your response too. I've got to be doing something wrong. Why does you Year column have an expression in it too? what is in that column?

Comment: @dcdeez, apologies for the screenshot, the expression in **Year** is fine as `Max(Fields!Year.Value)`... I had been playing around with something and took the screenshot at the wrong time - I have updated now. Maybe starting a new test report based on some sample data like I did as a control will help with your other issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that it's working as intended - the LOOKUPSET() function is returning *all* records from your dataset where the Company matches.  You need to either tighten your criteria in your use of the LOOKUPSET() function, or add some custom code to go through the returned array and purge duplicates.

One option for tightening up the lookup might be to add a calculated field to your dataset that concatenates the Company name and the Year together, which, at least looking at your sample data, would provide the slightly more unique key you're looking for.

Comment: Is there any reason why the above suggested solution wouldn't be filtering by date and including all values still?