# How to get multiple row data in single row using comma separation in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have to create one report in SSRS Reporting. Right Now I am getting data from SP as below:

```
Col1 Col2
A123 cust1
A123 cust2
A123 cust3
```

My requirement is to show result as below:

```
A123 cust1, cust2, cust3
```

Can anyone advice how can I do it?

Comment: You should be able to use a matrix to accomplish that. 
Check out this question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036335/ssrs-pivoting-a-column

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to handle it in the query and bring it into the report as comma separated list.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(col1 VARCHAR(10), col2 VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES 
    ('A123', 'cust1'),
    ('A123', 'cust2'),
    ('A123', 'cust3'),
    ('A125', 'cust1'),
    ('A125', 'cust2'),
    ('A125', 'cust3')

SELECT DISTINCT
    ot.col1,
    STUFF(
        (SELECT ', ' + CAST(it.col1 AS VARCHAR(10))
        FROM #temp it
        WHERE it.col1 = ot.col1
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') as List
FROM
    #temp ot

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22153473/ssrs-combining-values-within-columns-from-multiple-rows-when-grouped